# WDK C++ Project Needs to change debug compiler strictness

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, driver, wdk

I'm relatively new at drivers with WDK and Visual Studio.

When I compile project in debug mode I get no warnings or errors and project compiles and runs fine. However, when I compile in release mode, compilation stops and I get an error stating that a warning was found and is being treated as an error. The details of this are dumped into a log file found at the project root dir.

What I would like to do is have the compiler in debug mode be as strict as the release mode compiler. Currently they are both at default. The release mode seems stricter. I am using VS 2010 and WDK.  I'm not sure how to do this. It would be ideal if this setting was at the VS level and not at a per project level.

Also, It would be great if the warnings would show up in VS IDE instead of a log file.

Comment: Is this a driver for Windows 8?  If not, why are you building with Visual Studio?

Comment: Drivers can be built with VS only starting with VS2012. For earlier version the VS can serve only as an IDE. And target OS is irrelevant here, it doesn't have to be Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has different configuration setting for debug and release mode.

Check whether do you have relevant configuration in project > project properties -> linker etc......

If there is mismatch between debug and release mode configuration then change it. This should work

--Ali Chachar
--Pakistan

Answer (score 0):

There are code differences in the debug and release compilation that may lead to warnings unrelated to strictness of the compiler. Most noticeable is in the logs; in the release version `KdPrint/KdPrintEx` calls will be discarded. There is a good chance that some of your function input parameters are used for printing only and in case it's being omitted you'll end up with unused parameter warnings - this is the most frequent difference in debug vs. release compilations.

Even if you have a VS2010 solution, your driver isn't being compiled with the VS compiler but rather with the WDK compiler so VS settings are irrelevant here. You can migrate your solution to VS2012 which have driver support integrated.